# Get column name along with datatype in sql string

Tags: sql-server

I want to get column name and their datatype in single line string as shown below

```
cusnum varchar(100), name varchar(100), address1 varchar(100), address2 varchar(100), address3 varchar(100)
```

I used `sp_columns` stored procedure but it gives all the properties of columns. Also since it is system stored procedure I cannot edit it.

I would like to find another way to get this result. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, using the information of [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql)

```
SELECT STUFF(CAST((
  SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + 
    CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 0 THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(255))+ ')' 
    WHEN NUMERIC_PRECISION > 0 THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(10)) + CASE WHEN NUMERIC_SCALE > 0 THEN ',' + CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE '' END + ')'
    ELSE DATA_TYPE END
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS
VARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 2, '') AS columns
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1d3c1321e7efe8cb9b29140c099ef56)